# Present a view above the navigation bar but below some other screen content

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

Currently I have a navigation stack, which is displaying a view. It has a subview `floater` that takes up a portion of the screen, like so:

```
+--------+
| navbar |
+--------+
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
+--------+
|floater |
+--------+
```

Now, I want to present a view `infoSheet` modally that animates from the bottom of the screen; eventually, its final state should be **behind the floater** but **in front of the navigation bar**, like so:

```
+--------+
|        |
|        |
|  info  |
|  Sheet |
|        |
|        |
|        |
+--------+
|floater |
+--------+
```

I understand if we just want to present something in front of everything else in the window, we have some ways to do it, such as adding the `infoSheet` as a subview of the `navigationController.view`. However, since we also need the `floater` to be in front at all times, including when the `infoSheet` is animating into view, I believe that approach wouldn't work.

Comment: Cant u just also add the floater to `navigationController.view`?

Comment: Alternatively you can bring any subview to `front` by invoking [bringSubview(toFront:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622541-bringsubview) if you need.

Comment: As mentioned at the bottom of the question, the floater should be in place while the `infoSheet` is **animating** into view.